# are the "request" and "response" variables or values are predefined in java ee?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, request, response

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletTemplate extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest ***request***,
                      HttpServletResponse ***response***)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    }

}
```

In the above code example, is the request and response is predefined i.e. can i use any other name instead of them, if they are predefined in which package are they defined?
i have another question what is the job of ServletException i mean i know it handles the exceptions but my question is, is it necessary to use it in every progaramm i wanna know its detail function

Answer (score 3):

You can name *any* variable in a Java program with *any* name you want. It doesn't matter, the rules for implementing the methods in an interface or overriding the methods from a superclass dictate that the parameter *types* must match (same types, same order, same number), but the names don't matter - at all. This has nothing to do with Java EE, it's just how programming languages work.

Regarding the `ServletException`: a quick look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) reveals that the exception is being thrown in the `doGet()` method defined in the `HttpServlet` superclass, so any subclass that overrides the method must throw it, too.

Both of your questions are related with the way that inheritance and overriding work in Java, they're not Java EE-specific. I'd suggest you first study the documentation regarding inheritance and overriding in Java, before beginning to write more complex code, you seem to have trouble grasping how OO concepts apply in Java.

Answer (score 1):

They are just name for the arguments that you are overiding. In essentia your class  ServletTemplate inherits of HttpServlet, then if you want to provide functionality for request sent by GET method you must override it from the parent class, the name of the variables is indifferent the rules for overriding methods in Java are:

- Maintain the same signature of the method, where the signature of the method.

  - The signature is composed by the name of the method and the argument list (doesn't matter the names but the types are important).
- Don't define a accessor modifier more restrictive (by example from public to private).

So you can implement the method as follows (if you want)

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest x,
    HttpServletResponse y) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out = y.getWriter();
}
```

You can't invert the parameter the following is WRONG:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletResponse response,
     HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out = y.getWriter();
}
```